# default homepage not displaying

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have somewhat bizzarre situation... on my localhost when I debug the project all the pages are visible and first page (default page) is visible upon startup.

When I publish the project and move it to server all the pages are accessible and visible except the default (Home/Index).

My global.asax is ok, nothing is reporting any errors but when site is opened only the blank page is visible.

Could this be something with IIS? Since it's configured normally and we've event applied that hotfix for displaying pages without extensions (but it didn't work before that, tho).

Comment: WHat about paths. If you havent used virtual paths, these can be thrown off when moved. As the path is different, so its looking for things in the wrong place. A virtual path would always know where to look, as its relative to your project. By virtual path I mean use of the syntax `~/`

Comment: I'm doublechecking now... But I've used virtual paths everywhere possible.

EDIT:

 routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        ) 

This is my global.asax part of the code... maybe "~/Home"?

Comment: That bit is fine. That is just specifying the controller name. It might be something else. Sorry I cant help

Comment: Could it be that code IS ok and that something with IIS is misconfigured? In webforum you have to assign the default page type etc. Do we need to instruct the adminstrator to look for something like that?

Comment: We've sorted it out... it seems that the client's system administrators forgot to install the windows authentication but reported that they did. So that resulted in an error listed above.